# Getting error while using optic API to get count of certain column data for a data range from TDE views in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I am new to MarkLogic and need help in a issue debugging.
I have created a view with MarkLogic TDE and would like to get the count of records for some date range from that view.

I have checked the option of trying optic API in this.

Tried this XQuery which gives me an error saying the `BookingCreateDt` is not available in the view, but it actually exists in my template view.

Can you please spare some time to check the problem.

Query :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op=http://marklogic.com/optic at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
op:from-view("GTM2_Shipment", "Shipment_View", "")
=> op:select(("Ancillary_QuotePrice", "transMode"))
  =>op:where(
   
      op:and((
        op:eq(op:col('transMode'), 'Sea')
         ,
        op:gt(op:col('BookingCreateDt'), '2022-03-21T15:03:20')
      ))
      )
=>op:limit(1)
=>op:result()
```

And it returns this error -

> [1.0-ml] SQL-NOCOLUMN: Column not found: BookingCreateDt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your op.select() limits the rest of the results to just the  2 columns you mention("Ancillary_QuotePrice", "transMode").

Therefore, the columns you are testing against do not exist.

try:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op=http://marklogic.com/optic at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
op:from-view("GTM2_Shipment", "Shipment_View", "")
=>op:where(   
      op:and((
        op:eq(op:col('transMode'), 'Sea')
         ,
        op:gt(op:col('BookingCreateDt'), '2022-03-21T15:03:20')
      ))
      )
=> op:select(("Ancillary_QuotePrice", "transMode"))
=> op:limit(1)
=> op:result()
```

However, your code just gives you one result in database order. The results have nothing to do with counting records.  Perhaps that is what you want - but it does not match the title. If you are looking for a count:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op=http://marklogic.com/optic at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
op:from-view("GTM2_Shipment", "Shipment_View", "")
=>op:where(   
      op:and((
        op:eq(op:col('transMode'), 'Sea')
         ,
        op:gt(op:col('BookingCreateDt'), '2022-03-21T15:03:20')
      ))
      )
=> op:group-by((), op:count(op:col("theCount"), op:col("transMode")))
=> op:result()
```

This would result in one record with a column called theCount holding the count of records matching your where clause. I used transMode since I know it existed in all records based on the where clause. you could use any column.

Comment: Thanks David , it works to give me a count.
Can we use dateadd function here to get count for some date range.

Comment: xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
op:from-view("GTM2_Shipment", "Shipment_View", "")
=>op:where(   
      op:and((
        op:eq(op:col('transMode'), 'Rail')
         ,
      op:sql-condition("dateadd(month,-6,'BookingCreateDt')")
      
      ))
      )
=> op:group-by((), op:count(op:col("Rail_AncillaryCost"), op:col("Ancillary_QuotePrice")))
=> op:result()

Comment: I am using this which gives me an error - OPTIC-INVALARGS: (err:FOER0000) Invalid arguments: map argument is not an expression

Comment: For such items, you need to use runtime evaluation of the right side, you get the map error because columns and such are stored internally as maps.  Please *open a new question* with a clear title and example as above and expected.  There is a clear answer  for you - but answering followup questions in comments degrades the value of stackOverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks David. I have posted my follow up query in a separate question. Here is the link please -https://stackoverflow.com/q/72742034/18123235